# Constant won't change after class replaced in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, constants, tomcat6

I have deployed a application on Tomcat 6 and after I deployed I wanted to do some changes on my constant class and I uploaded only the constant class (`.class` file) into exploded war file.

And even after I restart the server several times the changes I made wouldn't show.

All I changed was some strings in constants. What would you suggest me to do other than uploading war file again?

Comment: why is uploading the *.war* file again not an option? As Joachim Sauer pointed out, you know need to recompile and re-deploy every *.class* file using your constant.  Btw, a "constant" is something like, say, PI.  The value of PI is unlikely to change between two deployments.  That's what constants should be.  Constant that can change aren't really constant and should probably be stored using another mean.  For example if you have something saying *official language = "DE"* that could then change to "FR" then it's typical to store such a "constant that is not really one" in a DB.

Comment: I actually uploaded my war file into production server so I couldn't upload it again.(It takes such a long time for me). I had to change my constant because of a misspelled word. Lucky for me I had to upload only another 5 class files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **will have to** recompile all classes that reference those `String` constants.

Note that a `static final` field of a primitive type or of type `String` that is initialized with a [compile time constant value](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313) (a so called [constant variable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#10931)) will be inlined when they are used in other classes.

In other words if you have these classes:

```
public class Constants {
  public static final int FOO = 42;
}

public class Bar {
  public void frobnicate() {
    System.out.println(Constants.FOO);
  }
}
```

Then **at compile time** the value of `FOO` will be compiled into the `.class` file of `Bar`, meaning that `Bar` no longer references `Constants` at runtime!

This also means that any change of `FOO` will have no effect on `Bar` *until* you re-compile `Bar` with the new `Constants.class`.

This effect is discussed at length in [JLS §13.4.9 `final` Fields and Constants](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4.9).

One way to avoid this problem in the future is to ensure that your "constants" are not interpreted as constant variables by the compiler. One way to do this is to move the assignment of a value from an initializer to a simple assignment via a static initializer block:

```
public class Constants {
  public static final int FOO;

  static {
    FOO = 42;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked just as you said. A valuable reply with a lesson, I won't forget this anymore.